# TypeError: Cannot read property 'tap' of undefined when loading svg

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have a React app which I´m building with webpack. I´m trying to include a svg file reference in my build, but I keep getting this error: `ERROR in   TypeError: Cannot read property 'tap' of undefined`
Here are some info about my build:

```
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^9.0.0",
    "svg-url-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.52.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0"
```

```json
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: {
    main: './src/main.tsx',
  },
  output: { path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist') },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
          'style-loader',
          // Translates CSS into CommonJS
          'css-loader',
          // Compiles Sass to CSS
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        loader: 'svg-url-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html',
    }),
    new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
      filename: '[name].js.map',
      exclude: ['vendor.js'],
    }),
  ],
};
```

And the full error:

```sh
ERROR in   TypeError: Cannot read property 'tap' of undefined

  - ExternalModuleFactoryPlugin.js:17 ExternalModuleFactoryPlugin.apply
    [xx]/[webpack]/lib/ExternalModuleFactoryPlugin.js:17:37

  - ExternalsPlugin.js:16
    [xx]/[webpack]/lib/ExternalsPlugin.js:16:63


  - Hook.js:14 Hook.CALL_DELEGATE [as _call]
    [yy]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:14:14

  - Compiler.js:1086
    [yy]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:1086:23


  - Hook.js:18 Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync]
    [yy]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:18:14

  - Compiler.js:1083 Compiler.compile
    [yy]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:1083:28

  - Compiler.js:532 Compiler.runAsChild
    [yy]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:532:8

  - child-compiler.js:110
    [xx]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/child-compiler.js:110:21
```

Can someone please tell me what I´m doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I tried to run the webpack using  webpack-cli. I fixed the issue by downgrading html-webpack-plugin from "5.5.0" to "4.3.0"